# How can write" If for all I>=2 a(I) =b(I) then x=x+3 " in GAMS?

Tags: gams-math

How can I write this if statement :(I is a set , and a,b are parameter and x is variable)

```
 If for all I>=2  we have , a(I) =b(I) then x=x+3 .
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use loop as follow:

```
 Loop (i$(i.val>2  and a(I)=b(I) ),
        X=x+3;
            );
```